# Reading large size text file and populate into a gridview within less time

Tags: c#, file, c#-4.0

I'm working with large file of `2GB` size with around 36 lakhs of records, here i want to read the particular file and show the space seperated fields in an gridview within less time. Does anyone have any idea please share your thoughts here. Thanks in advance.

I did an example using streamreader and its taking `20 sec` to read `134MB` file, is there any other way we can read it much faster?

Comment: What is your file format, simple text file? one record per line?

Comment: yes, its simple text file and one record per line whith space seperated column, something like; data x-asix y-axis

Comment: Also how are you doing your parsing, do you ReadLine -> Process one line at a time? You might try to read several lines in one go, store them into a string[] and then do the processing on the list of elements.

Comment: yes im using streamReader.ReadLine() using a while loop and populating to a data table and populating the same to the gridview. would like to know how we can read block by block of file content and populate into the gridview.

Comment: Also do you save the files yourself ? Or is it sometime provided to you, so you have to deal with that format?

Comment: its already saved file. no change in the format.

Comment: Is it feasible to only read in some lines at a time, then wait for the user to page to the next batch before reading the rest?

Comment: yes Bobson I am also looking for the same, im thinking that will read some lines and display in gridview when scroll or paging happens other part need to read. How we can do this?